# Java code does not return anything even though it is supposed to

Tags: java, oop

I'm just new to Java OOP, and I hardly understand about the class and stuff. I tried to write some code to understand but I didn't succeed. Here is my code, I expected it to return the number of eggs but I don't know why it returns nothing.

```
class EggCounter {
    private int egg;
    {
        egg = 0;
    }
    public void eggAdd()
    {
        egg = egg + 1;
    }
    public void eggBreak()
    {
        egg = egg - 1;
    }
    public void eggAddDozen()
    {
        egg = egg + 12;
    }
    public int getEgg()
    {
        return egg;
    }

 }
public class EggTest
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        EggCounter egg = new EggCounter();
        egg.eggAdd();
        egg.eggAddDozen();
        egg.eggBreak();
        egg.getEgg();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do nothing with the return value?

Comment: what about printing the egg.getEgg() so you can see what it returns

Comment: You can make use of binary operators. e.g., replace `egg = egg + 12;` with `egg += 12;`

Answer (score 2):

It does return `12`. Replace the `egg.getEgg();` line in your main method with `System.out.println(egg.getEgg());` and you will notice it prints `12`.

Answer (score 2):

It is returning, it's just that you do nothing with the return value of `getEgg`. What you need to do is store it into the variable or do something with it. `return <value>` only returns the given value to the callee, you must store it to use it. Example:

```
int eggCount = egg.getEgg();
System.out.println(eggCount);
```

Here, the assignment of `eggCount` calls `egg.getEgg()`. The call resolves when the number of eggs is returned, which assigns the return value to `eggCount`. Finally, it will print out `eggCount`. If you need the result of `egg.getEgg()` later, you can simply just output the following:

```
System.out.println(egg.getEgg());
```

How this works is the method `egg.getEgg()` is called. The return value is then resolved, which is passed into the print statement. This gets rid of storing it into a variable you can use later.